# Google Play Game Services is Unable to authorise my app in developer console

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to add Google Play Game Services into my game. I've followed each step in adding it into my app up to authorisation. When I click **authorise your app now**, it displays a text with waiting, loading and there after a white window opens with no response.

I have attached screenshots along with this post. Please let me know my mistakes if any or any possible solutions

[image: Authorise Button]

[image]

This is the white screen after clicking

Comment: Did you find any solutions for the problem? I got the same thing, tried with different browsers, different devices but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: No, I dodn't get any solution yet. I've stopped using Google Play game Services on Android version. I am using GameCenter for my iOS version. How ridiculous is that right? At least it give some error message stating our mistake if nay....

Comment: How do you even get to this screen? I cannot find it in latest iteration of UI.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error and turns out I hadn't accepted the new Google Play Services TOS and other policies to accept etc.

The popup to accept said new TOS comes up when I go back to the main Google Play Developer Console and then click Google Play Services. Then it works like a charm.

Comment: Hey, It is now authorising. But at least it should give some message to the user about his mistakes. It simply does nothing. I really hate such behaviour.

Comment: I have accepted the new TOS and I am still having the same issue as above. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too and it took me a long time to fix it.

1. First, you go to "authorise your app now" panel.
2. Go to the homepage: https://console.developers.google.com/
3. Select your app
4. Now look at app popup
5. Click the success button
6. Go to the "authorise your app now" panel, reset homepage
7. Click "authorise your app now".